# threads vs. pthread in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, pthreads, freebsd

I wonder what the different is between the options 'THREADS' and 'PTHREAD' when I compile perl 5.16 (and other version) from port source in freebsd?

Is the PTHREAD the posix-threading? (because -pthread) And if so, is it prefered to 'THREADS'? (because it seems to be preselected) even on freebsd? And what is 'THREADS' (Kernel threads?) on the other hand? What are the pros and cons?

Could I use both in one installation? Is it sensefull?

There is not to much to find around in combination with perl, as far as I can see.

thanks a lot
jimmy

Comment: hum... Perl only has one threading model (`-Dusethreads`)

Comment: hmm :) Ok compiling it with 'THREADS' changes the config args from -Dusethreads=n to -Dusethreads=y. The 'PTHREADS' adds '-pthread' to the ldflags. So, I guess it's not just kidding. It makes a difference, but I wonder what?! :/

Comment: Perl used to have a different model of threading. It was very broken. You're probably trying to access that.

Comment: What is this "it"? What are you using? "THREADS" and "PTHREAD" are not found anywhere in the Perl distribution. If you want threads, you pass `-Dusethreads` to Configure. If you don't, you don't.

Comment: Hmm. It is perl. I guess you missed the 'freebsd' thing in my question.... I add a tag for this, because it seems to be confusing.

Comment: No, I didn't. Your choice of OS has nothing to do with my question. Where is it you are reading about "THREADS" and "PTHREAD"? Those words are not found anywhere in the Perl distribution.

Comment: Then you probably don't know how one installs a bsd source port in freebsd. The options I'm asking about are set while running the Makefile of the perl port. The config args and ldflags I was naming are the changes you can see when you grep 'perl -V' for 'thread' after compilation. Just wanted to show what happens. So, finally it's a question about a difference in "-Dusethreads=n" and "-Dusethreads=y" and using '-pthreads' or not in the linker flags, if you want it breaking down to a source install on e.g. linux in my understanding.....

Comment: @ikegami, `pthreads` are mentioned [here in `perlthrtut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Synchronization-and-control). @JimmyKoerting: but it's simply comparing the thread model in Perl to the POSIX model of pthreads. [Here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Pthread)

Comment: @Axeman, I didn't ask if and where pthreads are mentioned. I asked where "THREADS" and "PTHREAD" are.

Comment: Well, again, it's `-Dusethreads` you should be using. `-Dusethreads=y` is apparently equivalent, so that's surely fine, but that's not the documented flag. `-pthreads` isn't `-Dusethreads`, so it's not right. What else do you want!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using threads is as others have described it of course.

The link with pthread means that your perl is built with the -pthread flag. This has a subtle but important effect. It means that when perl starts up, the libc data that maintains state for threads is initialized. This means that if your perl calls dlopen() on a library which is threaded, it will work properly, instead of hanging.

PS. I'm actually the person who wrote and committed the PTHREAD option to the port. I actually discovered some perl modules which dlopen()'d some threaded libs and caused perl to hang. Took me a while to figure out why. Trust me, you want the PTHREAD option on. I'm actually thinking of removing the option to turn it off. For more info, see FreeBSD PR 163512 and 163878. We probably should push this option upstream so that perl uses this by default on FreeBSD. Anything that may call dlopen() should really be built with -pthread.

Comment: I just love you!  And yes, in regards to what you mentioned and referenced, it sounds like a good idea to make it just default. Thanks Again!

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I proposed to always link perl with pthreads: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122906